# Best STL container to use

Tags: c++, stl

I am developing a text based container library application to store song objects, I will also be creating artist and album objects.

It will implement the following functionality

Add items to the library

- Remove items from the library
- Edit any property of an item in the library
- Search for items in the library.
- Sort items in the library by any of the items’ properties

When the application first loads the library will be loaded from a text file.

I am struggling to decide what the most appropriate STL container to use for each of the objects should be. I thought about using vector but that would allow duplicates.

The other question I have is if i say a song class, should I have a separate class called SongLibrary that contains all the song objects or should I just store them in a container in the main?

Comment: it seems like you need the set data structure. in C++ , it's either `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say just create a `SongLibrary` to encapsulate the song storage implementation and the container used. Having the container exposed to the main class will pollute it, make it harder to test and more difficult to extend (e.g. shuffling).

And by doing so, you can later more easily change the container used without changes to the callers.

As for the container, there's a lot to consider, e.g.: do you need faster read time or write time? Usually we prefer the former, so in that case index-based containers would be better. Anyways, this might just end up being premature optimization so I'd say just choose the `std::set` since it already handles duplicates, which makes your life easier. Then, if that proves to be not enough, you can always modify your library class.

Comment: So by that do you mean i will have a class called song, and a class called SongLibrary witch contains the set of all the songs and the methods for adding, modifying etc..

Comment: @MichaelGrinnell Ideally, yes, but only if songs proves to be complex enough to be a class itself. With `SongLibrary` you aready have complexity: you need to expose a simple API to handle an updatable list of songs that can also be sorted, while using some container from the standard library. Now if a song needs to have an album name, a release year, an artist name, time and so on then yes, I see it a having its own class.

Comment: To me the idea is to [keep it simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) whenever you can, that's why I don't believe you should spend too much time deciding what container to use when in the end it might not even make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a vector with a struct and 3 maps for fast finding:

```
struct song { std::string name, album, artist; };
std::vector<song> songs;
std::map<std::string, int> name2song, album2song, artist2song;
```

The accessing functions are pretty self-explanatory.

You can encapsulate all of it inside a class of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud use sqlite db, then you can use SQL commands for each of your actions.

For example: you can create table for song files with the following columns:

`rowid (unique),title,artist,album,year,filename(unique)`.

each of your actions can be achived by SQL command:

- Remove items from the library - `delete` sql command
- Edit any property of an item in the library - `update` sql command
- Search for items in the library - `select field,rowid` + put result in `std::map<string,rowid>`
- Sort items in the library by any of the items’ properties - `select ... order by`

Comment: I would love to use a database but for the purposes of this i need to use a text file, thanks anyway.